# Sql Query Problem

Tags: oracle

i have problem when joining tables(left join)
table1:

```
id1  amt1
1    100
2    200
3    300
```

table2:

```
id2  amt2
1    150
2    250
2    350
```

my Query:
select id1,amt1,id2,amt2 from table1
left join table2 on table2.id1=table1.id2

my supposed o/p is:

```
      id1 amt1  id2 amt2
row1: 1   100   1    150
row2: 2   200   2    250
row3: 2   200   2    350
```

i want o/p in row3 as

2 null 2 350

ie i want avoid repetetion of data(amt1)
friends help!

Comment: Please take some time to format your question and make it readable...

Comment: -1 for posting the same question again instead of engaging with the responses you got yesterday.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459993/problem-with-joining-db-tables/1460064#1460064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LEAD and [LAG](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) gives acces to previous or following rows in oracle.

```
SELECT id1, decode(amt1, lag(amt1) over (order by id1, id2), '', amt1) amt1, 
       id2, amt2 
FROM table1 left join table2 on table2.id1=table1.id2
ORDER BY id1, id2
```

The order of the query and the order given to the lag function should be the same.

**Explanation:**
If the current am1 is the same as the preceding amt1 (preceding in the given order) then omit the value.

**EDIT**
According to your comment, add an additional check for id changes.

```
SELECT id1, 
       decode(id1, lag(id1) over (order by id1, id2), 
           decode(amt1, lag(amt1) over (order by id1, id2), '', amt1), 
           amt1) amt1, 
       id2, amt2 
FROM table1 left join table2 on table2.id1=table1.id2
ORDER BY id1, id2
```

Use the same LAG feature to check for id changes. The expression is a bit more complex, but its comparable with a nested if statement.

Comment: If you think its working, mark the answer. It brings reputation for you too.

Comment: Hello your Query workd 4 me. but i hav a problem even if id is different and the amount is same the amt sets to null in 
u r query,...i am originally used this in a procedure with joins of number of tables

Answer (score 1):

select **distinct** id1,amt1,id2,amt2 from table1 left join table2 on table2.id1=table1.id2

try this ?